# getting the string array from fetchAll pdo

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I am facing something really strange and cant understand why I am getting this next result,
I have 2 files, index.php and send.php
send.php fetching from the DB list of users and index.php showing the list as table, in index.php I am using require send.php, in send.php i have this code

```
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
```

and its working great, but in index.php

```
    <?php if (isset($result)): ?>
        <pre>
            <?php print_($result); ?>
        </pre>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I am getting the array like this [0] => array

why?

Comment: print_() will not work. typo

Comment: Is any of that code inside a function or method by any chance

Comment: @Yolo I am guessing that is a typo in the question only otherwise OP would not get the output they suggest they are getting

Comment: Showing us more of the real code would probably get you a useful answer. As it stands we would just have to **make guesses!**

Comment: its really simple code, and about the typo its only in this post, and no its not in function or method, I continue to work in different method but its really wired i dont understand why its acting like this.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this question, and if so, please share the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Should be obvious, unlike `fetch()` where you iterate over each row `fetchAll()` returns a list of rows, each being in a separate index of the array.

```
$result[0]['column'];
        ^
        |-- first result.
```

So you should do this:

```
foreach($result as $row){
  echo $row['colname'];
}
```

This would make `$row` an array by default, where the key is the column name.

---

On a side note, if you want to check if you have results do the following:

```
// this:
if($result){}

// equals:
if(!empty($result)){}
```

Using `isset()` will cause unexpected behavior:

```
if(isset($result = false)){
  // query failed, but this code still executes.
}
```

Also trying to access a global variable defined in another script is bad practice, avoid doing it. Wrap your code in a small function instead:

```
function dbGetUsers(){
  // connect to db or whatnot.
  $sth = $pdo->prepare('....');

  if($sth->execute()){
    return $sth->fetchAll();
  } else {
    die('query failed '. __FILE__ . __LINE__ - 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you didnt understand me, 
then i am using print_r on the fetchAll variable i am getting the data correctly, but then i am using print_r in index.php (in index.php i am using require to the second page) an i am getting the reult of [0] => array, and the array is a string and not array itself, later i noticed that when i am trying to send the result via curl i am getting again the wired array.

Comment: Then somewhere in the line you are overwriting the variable `$result`, globals shouldn't be used like that anyways and you should use a function instead.

Comment: i double checked the $result, and its the only variable that i named it like that, and even the lenth of the array is the same just the value different.